# Android problem with retrieving values from firebase and submitting them on a listview

Tags: android, firebase

i have a problem with my code i can't appear data in my list view
i want to retrieve the falls from my users the specific date, time and location

bellow is my code

```
    l1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.historyListView);

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();   

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);         
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Fall fall = new Fall();
        fall.setDate(ds.child(user.getUid()).getValue(Fall.class).getDate());
        fall.setTime(ds.child(user.getUid()).getValue(Fall.class).getTime());
        fall.setLocation(ds.child(user.getUid()).getValue(Fall.class).getLocation());

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add(fall.getDate());
        array.add(fall.getTime());
        array.add(fall.getLocation());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),fall.getDate().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        l1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
  }
}
```

my db structure is the big ids are the user UID

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all `Fall` objects within your `falls` node, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("falls").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Fall fall = ds.getValue(Fall.class);
            Log.d(TAG, fall.getLocation());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be all locations of all `Fall` objects.

Comment: i get an error on Fall fall = ds.getValue(String.class); I think the right is                     Fall fall = ds.getValue(Fall.class);

Comment: You're right. My bad. Please see my updated answer. Does it down now?

Comment: thanks man it works but this line of code         uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
for what is it for ?

Comment: It adds the listener to that specific location.

Answer (score 0):

first of all is you need addListener at correct node.`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` is root reference if you addListener at root reference mean you retrieve all of your database data.

I recommend you read this [Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start)
And watch this [YoutubeLink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&index=1&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) for query data and set data correctly

Answer (score 0):

First of all You can straight cast Firebase data to Java Objects if Names are same or use  @PropertyName("custom_name_in_database")

```
Fall fallForAUser = ds.child(user.getUid()).getValue(Fall.class);
```

Always use datasnapshot.exists() as it make sure app don't crash on ds.child(). If data exists for given user it should be visible in list now.

Comment: can you please modify my code so can i understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to add the name of the Node from which you want the data, in your case it is falls. So, 
FirebaseReference fbr =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("falls");
Now you'll get all the data inside the falls node.

Comment: nothing happens it turns white screen and returns to the previous one